# C# Instrumentation

Tags: c#, instrumentation, trace, roslyn

What would be the easiest way to do instrumentation of C# code? By instrumentation I mean inserting my own pieces of the code to gather some dynamic information during the execution.

For example (star represents some unimportant piece of code):

```
for (int i=0; i<s.Length-2; ++i) {
  if (*)
    s = s.Substring(1, s.Length-2);
}
```

I would like to catch *0* being assigned to *i*, *i* incremented and assignment and call to a *Substring*. By catching a method call, I mean that I have information what method it is and values of the arguments or similar.

I tried to do it with [the Roslyn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Roslyn) by wrapping method calls with my own wrappers which could a) intercept values and store them (for example), b) call actual method and c) return this result. Only problem is that this approach is really error-prone and difficult (because there are many different cases to cover).

I wonder if there is already some library for this purpose or someone knows easier way of doing it. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio Professional? It does instrumented builds for you. It also does sampling instead, which is less intrusive but less accurate too.

Comment: What I forgot to mention is that I want to do it automatically. Right now, I take *source code* of a program, instrument it (as I described above), compile and run it, and while running I collect data (every step is automated, so input is source code and output data). So, using VS isn't really a good option...

Comment: If you want to instrument code dynamically, at runtime, at the IL level, you can do that with ICLRProfiling APIs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd695931.aspx

Comment: @Ivan My point was that if you are just collecting information such as how much time was spent in various methods and how many times particular methods or properties were accessed, Visual Studio can do that for you automatically without you needing to change any code.

Comment: @Matthew I'd also like to collect all the arguments and similar data and store it and compute with it perhaps. I also couldn't make a program which could instrument any piece of code and output something or use it like a procedure in some other program?

Comment: @EricLippert I am afraid this might be on a too low level. I want to combine trace information with variables, methods and data present in the source code (that's the reason I have started with the Roslyn)

Comment: @Ivan: Then CLR profiling is too low a level, yes.  Roslyn is a better bet.

Answer (score 1):

You could use tools like :
- Cecil
- ReFrameworker
- MBEL
- RAIL